# How can I prevent anybody sending requests to my server?

Tags: api, express, http, security, server

**Context:**
I have written a simple polling app using the PERN stack (Postgres, Express, ReactJS, and NodeJS). The client sends a GET request to the server, this returns the question data and displays it to the user. The user then selects option A or B. This is then sent via a POST request to the server which then triggers the database to be updated.

My issue is that anybody can view the RAW HTML of the client and see the server URL and send a POST/GET request of the same format themselves. Even if I used an authentication token, surely somebody could view the RAW HTML again, see the GET request and do it themselves?

It's possible I am completely missing something here so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no way to prevent other requests being sent to your server.  Your server is on the internet. Anyone can send to it.  The usual solution here is that you require some form of account login credential with every incoming request (except login requests) and you detect serial abuse and lock the offending account.

Comment: Actually this is a good question. I am curious about the methods people use to dis-allow packages like `requests`, which give the attacker the capability to do DOS attacks pretty easily.

Comment: @jfriend00 I think this may be the answer. My question from there would be even if I require authentication, surely anybody can still get their own token and from there still send their own GET/POST requests.

Comment: @Mooncrater - One would typically implement rate limiting to avoid having one client send too many request.  This is what the big boys like Google do.

Comment: @jfriend00 So basically IP based limiting. But what about DDOS?

Comment: @Mooncrater - No, IP based limiting is not at all what I said. If you read my comments, I said you require an account as a credential and you do rate limiting on all accesses for that account. DDOS is a large topic as there are many types of attacks so there is no general answer - you'd have to discuss a particular type of attack. Some protections must be handled at the network layer with routers and firewalls and other network infrastructure, others at the app level. DDOS is not what this question is about.  If you want to ask more specifically about that, then please write your own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is a little bit unclear. If you mean the application layer, there is no way to prevent it unless you disconnect it from the internet which is not possible. There are some ways that you can reduce the load and keep track of each request - the only thing that everyone does.

**Limiting requests / Rate limit**

If there are some public endpoints which don't include any authentications, it's better to limit the number of requests that have been sent from the same user in a specific period of time. There are some packages that you might check. This will help to reduce the server's load.

**Authentication**

You may want to keep track of users' requests, then you should authenticate them using a token or something like that. In that case, even the clients that send a request to you, won't change any data on the backend until they get authorized.

***Network layer***

You can disable the public access to your server and allow only specific IPs to send requests (whitelisting). Even in that case, you don't prevent sending requests, you just ignore them. The other way is to use a CDN provider to protect your services from DDoS attacks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am more talking from a security standpoint. I suppose the question should be: 'How can I ensure only requests from the actual client are accepted by the server'.

Comment: @Jambla Well if the question is about **Accepting**, then the **Authentication** part will meet the needs.

Comment: @Jambla i understand your confusion, but as Emad explained, it is impossible to do what you ask. The best way forward is authentication, but people can ALWAYS reverse-engineer application code if they really want to.
you should make sure malicious users CANNOT do something wrong on your server. This is best done by authentication and authorization (and everything else in Emad's answer). Differentiating between your app and an imposter is near impossible.